# Salesforce1 problem

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, iframe

I have made an app for the Salesforce1 Platform, I can access it on-line through https://.lightning.force.com/one/one.app.

The app works perfectly on-line, however when I open my app inside Salesforce1 on my iPhone. The app takes ages to load, then it goes blank or crashes - after this nothing else happens.

All I have done is put an iFrame inside of it, with a link to a website to display that whole website inside the iFrame.

As I said this all works perfectly on the  website version of Salesforce1 but not on the actual app on my iPhone.

Does anyone know the answer for this?

Is it because its a whole other page it crashes it, because of so much memory? or when I scroll its trying to load more of the page and crashing it?